# Using CIP in C# as the Target?

Tags: c#, ethernet, network-protocols, industrial

I see a lot of usage of CIP in C# as the originator. I've investigated this library : https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EEIP.NET. This one and all the other I've looked at are placing the user as the originator, looking to communicate with PLCs that are the targets.

Does anyone know a library that place the user as the target? Sendind Responses instead of requests?
In a project I'm doing I should use C# to make two computers communicate over CIP, but we are not the one initiating the communication (we should respond to the RegisterSession, Forward Open etc).

CIP was not chose by us but the client if you should ask.

So far i can initiate a TCP connection with a CIP simulator they provided, answer a register session request, receive a forward open request, and respond to it. But i'm a bit lost at the whole start communicating in udp stuff, so i'm looking to a library to ease off this step.

Comment: Use Google to go shopping, start with ".net cip library".  [Example](https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EEIP.NET).

Comment: This is the library  i mention in the question. It seems wonderful for scanners, not for the adapter side of things.